# Static content compression over Azure Web Role & Azure CDN not working

Tags: azure, gzip, azure-web-roles, http-compression, azure-cdn

My website is hosted on an **Azure WebRole** and the content is fetched using **Azure CDN**.
The main HTTP request itself is compressed, but the static content (css & js are the main issue here) isn't. 
The request is sent **with 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch'** header, but the response is **missing** the **'Content-Encoding: gzip'** and **'Vary: Accept-Encoding'** headers. 
It's important to note that **this happens when fetching the content both from and the CDN and directly from the WebRole**.

These are the relevant web.config sections:

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" doStaticCompression="true" />
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" noCompressionForHttp10="false" noCompressionForProxies="false">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

As you can see in the config, I've enabled compression for proxies and for HTTP 1.0, but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Anyone has an idea what's wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure CDN - Enabling HTTP Compression - Hosted Web Role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420004/azure-cdn-enabling-http-compression-hosted-web-role)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  Did you try turning on compression at the CDN level?  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-improve-performance/