# Azure CDN doesn't return gzipped data

Tags: azure, gzip, cdn, azure-blob-storage

I configured [gzip compression](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2012/03/05/enableing-gzip-compression-with-windows-azure-cdn-through-web-role/) with Windows Azure CDN, but CDN still gives un-gzipped data:

```
$ curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -I https://bbbdev.azureedge.net/images/512.png
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-MD5: GAXAIuQyL8MhCNc+BW1baw==
Content-Type: image/png
Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 12:59:45 GMT
Etag: 0x8D363B09C5AB6D6
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 15:30:57 GMT
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Vary: Origin
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-request-id: 60846501-0001-0042-23bb-9f72d0000000
x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
x-ms-write-protection: false
Content-Length: 11028
```

And I have `image/png` and `image/jpeg` added as "Formats to compress" - but no luck.

And the fact is - in our *origin* (Blob Storage) those files not compressed - we just put them in container using `self.blob.put_block_blob_from_path()` from Azure SDK.

As I found in a [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420004/azure-cdn-enabling-http-compression-hosted-web-role/10420101#10420101) - if files are not compressed on the *origin* side - CDN will not gzip them.

So - is there only way to "manually" (via script in fact) gzip them before `push` to Storage - or this can be done other way?

Comment: After 2-3 hours, when I checked it from home - suddenly all start working. I suppose - such settings (when manually add mime-types) also need time to apply, same as `entrypoint`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-improve-performance/#notes

"As with deploying new endpoints, CDN configuration changes take some time to propagate through the network. In most cases, you will see your changes apply within 90 minutes. If this is the first time you've set up compression for your CDN endpoint, you should consider waiting 1-2 hours to be sure the compression settings have propagated to the POPs before troubleshooting."

Glad everything works now!

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Thanks for the link - doesn't see it before. I made my setup using https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-troubleshoot-compression/ this article, and in comments, I asked it's author to update it. And he did :-) This is, btw, very pleasant Azure's side - it's support really ready to help. They not always can help, but - they trying :-)