# Azure CDN + Asp.net MVC Cloud Service compression for bundles not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cdn

I am using Azure CDN which is pointing to my Azure Cloud Service. I have enabled bundling for my JS and CSS files, and in BundleConfig I have set `bundles.UseCdn = true`.

Everything is working fine, except that JS & CSS bundles returned via CDN are not compressed. 
If I am not using CDN, bundles are returned compressed (I can see that Content-Encoding is gzip).

I have enabled compression on my CDN as you can see in pic below:

[image]

And in my ASP.net MVC web.config compression is also enabled, and it looks like this:

```
 <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
  <httpCompression>
    <dynamicTypes>
    <clear/>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="text/javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="text/css" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />

      <!-- HERE -->
      <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="image/png" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="image/jpg" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="image/jpeg" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/font-woff2" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
      <!-- HERE -->

      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
    <clear/>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="text/javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="text/css" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />

      <!-- HERE -->
      <add mimeType="image/png" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="image/jpg" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="image/jpeg" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/font-woff2" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
      <!-- HERE -->

      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
  </httpCompression>
```

Interestingly, for same CDN profile (but other endpoint) pictures do have Content-Encoding: gzip, so it seems that compression works fine on CDN also.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10434390/1284262) suggested adding smth. like `&group=smth.js` at the end of CDN URL, but that din't help.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried purging the bundled content and trying again?

Comment: Sure, couple of times, I have deployed my Cloud Service with different configurations and I have purged every time after deploy, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I created my MVC web application to check this issue and I did not configure `urlCompression` under my `web.config` file.

[image]

Without Azure CDN, the css/javascript would be compressed.

For test, I just CDN my whole web app via Azure CDN as follows:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** The Compression is enable by default and the formats to compress are the default settings.

Then, access the css/javascript links, they would be compressed as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems for me gzip is not enabled by default, when I commented out urlCompression part from web.config, my content was not gziped

Comment: Your compression screenshot looks strange. Have you checked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-new-endpoint) about creating the CDN profile?

Comment: I am not sure why you find it strange, if you follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-improve-performance) and scroll to **Premium tier** it looks exactly same (expect I have bit more types)